# Android Studio 3.0 Update Error

Tags: android, android-studio, debug

Bom hoje apareceu uma atualização para o Android Studio e como sempre coloquei para atualizar normalmente. Ao acabar de atualizar pedia pra baixar algumas versões de gradle e coisas assim, só instalei de deixei rodar normalmente. Porem o debug\manifest da um erro na hora de compilar.

log:

```
Error:(2) error: attribute 'package' in tag is not a valid Java package name: 'com.example.joao_.monitoclub'.

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:1java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.joao_.monitoclub"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" /> <!-- Required permission for App measurement to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.joao_.monitoclub.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.joao_.monitoclub.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: estou com mesmo problema, compartilho sua dor

Comment: Desabilitar o Aapt2 não é solução. Apenas suprime os erros.
O correto é adaptar o manifest, como referência nesta solução (em inglês):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976562/my-android-manifest-is-full-of-errors-after-updating-to-android-3-0-0

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei este atributo no arquivo gradle-wrapper.properties e funcionou.

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: não funcionou aqui

Comment: nao funcionou no meu tambem

Comment: desse modo resolveu meu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910532/android-studio-3-0-rc-2. essa opção deve ser alterada no glade.properties

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost muito obrigado , colocando no glede.properties funcionou corretamente de novo.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido !!
 coloque

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

em 
 glade.properties
e tudo volta ao normal.

Muito obrigado a todos pela contribuição.